# Populate a tableview with section category

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I  want to populate a data in uitableview. I have a different sections with different category and each category contains  different number of rows.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
        return allCategory.count;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *heading = [allCategory objectAtIndex:section];
    return heading;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    int count = 0;
     NSString *heading = [allCategory objectAtIndex:section];
    for (Product * cat  in productArry) {
        if ([cat.category containsString:heading]) {

            count ++;
        }
    }

    return count;

}
```

This is a code in which I return a number of rows on a basis of category.
For example I have a category name "Engine" which return one number of row and category name "Blocks" which return 2 number of rows. Now I want to populate a data against each category in "cellForRowAtIndexPath "method. How  can I populate a correct data against each category?

Comment: how many type of category in array?

Comment: There can be X amount of categories in the array Im guessing.

Comment: X amount of category @DarjiJigar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

```
- (Product *)dataForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int count = 0;
    NSString *heading = [self.allCategory objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    for (Product * product  in self.productArry) {
        if ([product.category containsString:heading]) {
            if (count == indexPath.row) {
                return product;
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Product *product = [self dataForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return nil;
}
```

**Option 2:**
Or you may want to make a filtered array

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *allCategory;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *productArry;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *products;
```

.m

```
- (NSArray *)products {
    if (!_products) {
        NSMutableArray *arrayCategoryProductArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for(int i =0 ;i< self.allCategory.count;i++){
            NSString *strCat = [self.allCategory objectAtIndex:i];
            NSArray *filteredarray = [self.productArry filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(category == %@)", strCat]];
            [arrayCategoryProductArray addObject : filteredarray];
        }
        _products = arrayCategoryProductArray;
    }
    return _products;
}
```

Input

```
<__NSArrayI 0x7866c8b0>(
<Product: 0x78668460; category = A; name = A1>,
<Product: 0x78663280; category = B; name = B1>,
<Product: 0x7866c750; category = A; name = A2>,
<Product: 0x7864c950; category = B; name = B2>,
<Product: 0x786610a0; category = B; name = B3>
)
```

Output

```
<__NSArrayM 0x798449b0>(
<__NSArrayI 0x79839050>(
<Product: 0x78668460; category = A; name = A1>,
<Product: 0x7866c750; category = A; name = A2>
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x798c7310>(
<Product: 0x78663280; category = B; name = B1>,
<Product: 0x7864c950; category = B; name = B2>,
<Product: 0x786610a0; category = B; name = B3>
)
)
```

So

```
- (Product *)dataForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Product *product = [[self.products objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return product;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Product *product = [self dataForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: option 2 is better

Comment: It can be better by re-write `- (NSArray *)products`, use `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` in a loop is not great for performance, E.g. have 100+ categories and run `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` in 100 times. Just loop productArry once to generate `- (NSArray *)products` is better.

Answer (score 1):

First you should filter out array by categories..Like below...

```
NSMutableArray *arrayCategoryProductArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i =0 ;i< allCategory.count;i++){
  NSString *strCat = [allCategory objectAtIndex:0];
  NSArray *filteredarray = [productArry filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(category == %@)", strCat]];
  [arrayCategoryProductArray addObject : filteredarray];
}
[YOUR_TBL reloadData];
```

Apply filter according to your requirement and check filtered result...
And in table method....

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

     NSArray *subDataArray = [arrayCategoryProductArray objectAtIndex:section];
     return subDataArray.count;

}
```

Comment: I already filtered the categories ... I only want to populate the data in tableview . @jinal

Comment: Then it's easy to display as i shown above in code...You can make one aray of all data for particular category...

Comment: Are you getting this?